# How to track download link in django?

Tags: python, django

I followed these method to track how much downloaded the file was. But `total_downloads` always remains same (it's 0). How to increment `total_downloads` field by 1 after every download?

My **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

class FilesAdmin(models.Model):
    id_no = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    loc = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    adminupload = models.FileField(upload_to='media')
    total_downloads = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**. In this program, I want to increment the number of downloads. But it's 0 in admin site.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import os
from .models import FilesAdmin

def index(request):
    context = {'file': FilesAdmin.objects.all()}
    return render(request,'libooki/index.html',context)


def download(request,path,pk):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path,'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(),content_type="application/adminupload")
            response['Content-Disposition']='inline;filename'+os.path.basename(file_path)
            n = FilesAdmin.objects.get(pk=pk)
            n.total_downloads += 1
            n.save()
            return response
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from libooki import views #here's libooki is my app name
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index,name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^download/(?P<path>.*)$',serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**index.html** from where people can download the file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for post in file%}
        <h2>{{post.name}}</h2>
        <a href="{{post.adminupload.url}}" download="{{post.adminupload.url}}">Download</a>

    {% endfor %}


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to get an instance of the `FilesAdmin` model. If the `path` you pass to the download view is an attribute of that model, you could use that to get the instance, otherwise you'll have to pass something which relates to it.

Comment: I understand, but how to pass an id in download function from urls.py? Can you please help sir?

Comment: You'd probably need to change what `post.adminupload.url` does so that it passes something you can get an object with. Probably just the PK.

Comment: does this really works ->  FilesAdmin.total_download.save()

Comment: @markwalker_ in views.py the paremeters would be request, path and id(pk). Can you please modify the code I given. Please don't bore at a beginner

Comment: I think none of your url hitting download function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Axios to download the file,

In the template, Try this-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>hello</title>
</head>

<body>
    {% for post in file %}
    <h2>{{post.name}}</h2>
    <button onclick="downloadFile('{{ post.adminupload.url }}', '{{ post.id }}')">Download file</button>
    {% endfor %}
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function downloadFile(file_url, id) {
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: file_url,
            responseType: 'blob',
            onDownloadProgress: event => {
                if (event.loaded === event.total) {
                    // send a GET request to the backend telling that download is complete
                    axios({
                            method: "GET",
                            url: "/post-downloaded/" + id, // send id of the post, user is downloading
                        })
                        .then(console.log("download incremented"))
                        .catch(error => console.log(error))
                }
            }
        }).then(response => {
            // download the file
            const aTag = document.createElement("a");
            aTag.href = URL.createObjectURL(resp.data);
            aTag.download = "filename." + resp.data.type.split("/")[1];
            aTag.click();
        })
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Now in the backend, create a route for **/post-downloaded/**

In your urls.py file-

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from libooki import views
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index,name='index'),
    path('post-downloaded/<int:pk>', views.post_downloaded), # add this route
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And in the views.py file create this-

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import FilesAdmin

def index(request):
    context = {'file': FilesAdmin.objects.all()}
    return render(request,'libooki/index.html',context)

def post_downloaded(request, pk):
    file = FilesAdmin.objects.get(pk=pk)
    file.total_downloads += 1
    file.save()
    return HttpResponse("download added")
```

This should get the work done

Answer (score 0):

You are not obtaining any instance of `FilesAdmin` to update. What's more, you don't seem to have any way to identify the files in the database. Your model stores the file and you can download it but you don't have any way to obtain an instance of `FilesAdmin` corresponding to the file you want to be downloaded. If you want the file path to identify the instances, I would add a field `path` to the model and save the file's url in there, since it is what you expect in the download request. Then, I would change the view as such:

```
def download(request,path):
    file = FilesAdmin.objects.get(path=path)
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path,'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(),content_type="application/adminupload")
            response['Content-Disposition']='inline;filename'+os.path.basename(file_path)
            file.total_downloads+=1
            file.save()
            return response
```

Keep in mind that this is not a correct way to do what you intend, you should identify unique instances of the model with a unique identifier (`id` in your case), but if you want to use the path, this is a way to do it.

Comment: I did your steps. But it seems the same problem (shownig 0)

Comment: Path isn't an attribute of `FilesAdmin`

Comment: @markwalker_ I know... That's exactly why I wrote the "I would add a field path to the model..." part...